# T lymphocytes and HIV-AIDS

Tags: hiv, lymphatic-system

in studying maturation of lymphocytes into two different types-T LYMPHOCYTES and B LYMPHOCYTES. it is mentioned that if a lymphocyte matures in thymus gland it becomes T LYMPHOCYTE and becomes B LYMPHOCYTE if matures in bone marrow {bursa region}.

also HIV virus attacks helper t lymphocytes . I was thinking that if we could make the initial immature lymphocytes in thymus made outside in vitro  { like from stem cells or likewise from clone etc or some other alternatives} and then inject them in patient so as to overcome their deficiency .

is it possible?

Comment: The deficit here is that HIV invades and depletes arguably the most important immune cells you've got: CD4+ T lymphocytes. The concept behind your question is sort of like an expensive bandage you always have to get when your CD4 counts drop into AIDS territory. Does that make sense? It's like feeding the virus more host cells without addressing the virus.

Comment: @CMosychuk, my point was regarding replenishment of depleted t-lymphocytes. We have produced clones, we know about totipotency of cells. Also hiv virus should be given some other treatment. What do you think? Do make me aware about this. Thanks